# Send Enter key using the mouse

Tags: mouse, accessibility, keybindings

I have to use the mouse a lot, but have to keep hitting enter as well. It would really help if I could use the mouse to send a global/system-level "enter" key event via triple click or something.

Why? Various programs and website forms I work with do not have a submit button to click, they rely on an "enter" keypress event. It's quite awkward to constantly move my hand from the mouse to the keyboard for one keypress every 20 seconds or so.

Is this possible?

*EDIT*

Not *Virtual Keyboard* or *Mouse Keys*.

Comment: Enter or Return?

Comment: Doing what ? for a dialog box there is a equivalent to return. If text then why is enter different to another key?

Comment: @MaxRied - Edited my post, I'm looking for a global/system level Enter (not return) event to fire.

Comment: Which websites (as they all have a button( and apps would have to be very non standard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) can be used for this purpose. You can configure gestures and actions that trigger keyboard shortcuts. You could trigger something that simulated the enter key being pressed using this tool.

Comment: haha, you did the input with the 10seconds difference on the same thing as I did, unbelievable :)

Comment: I will look into this. It may be more robust than what I need, but it may do the job. Thanks!

Comment: Can't say enough good stuff about BetterTouchTool, You have to pay for it now, but do it!

Answer (score 2):

1. I think you are asking about [virtual keyboard on Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/21/mac-virtual-keyboard-os-x/)

You can show it by doing this (screenshots are by the link provided above):

> - Open System Preferences and go to “Keyboard”, and look under the “Keyboard” tab
> - Check the box next to “Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar”
> - Pull down the newly visible Keyboard menu and choose “Show Keyboard Viewer”
> - Place the keyboard on screen in the desired location, and resize the newly visible keyboard as necessary by dragging the corners

2. Second option to use third party application for configuring shortcuts/mouse actions and guestures, alike [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/). There could be other Applications as well.

Comment: I do know about that feature, but it's not what I want. I don't need the full keyboard, just want a specific key, and would prefer not to have to mouse over something for it. I think I need a script for this.

Comment: @user179561, check my updated answer, extended per your request